# Seeking First High in Column

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Not needing max value in array, but rather first high.  For me, a high must be greater than the one following (next row up) and greater than the one preceding(next row down) less one.

I have two examples in this sheet, but don't know how to structure a single cell formula to return desired result.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/185zQHX0P2KC41DBuHHbv7K4onCdroTDKjT0DSKSM1IU/edit?usp=sharing

Listed in the sheet examples.

Comment: Would an Index formula work for this maybe?  I struggle with how to do Index function, but am guessing Index with multiple criteria would be best?  Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for comparison, this would be the more conventional index/match approach with offset ranges:

```
=ArrayFormula(index(M45:M49,match(1,(M45:M49>M44:M48)*(M45:M49>(M46:M50-1)),0)))
```

More generally using index with a named range:

```
=ArrayFormula(index(index(range,2):index(range,rows(range)-1),match(1,( index(range,2):index(range,rows(range)-1)>index(range,1):index(range,rows(range)-2) )*( index(range,2):index(range,rows(range)-1)>index(range,3):index(range,rows(range))-1) ,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: The minus one has to do with the next cell down.  If the next cell down minus 1 is less than the current then it would return true.  So if the current is greater than the cell above and the one below minus one then formula should return that value.  I tried modifying your formula to this, but it doesn't seem to work.   =ArrayFormula(index(M45:M49,match(1,(M45:M49>M44:M48)*(M45:M49>(M46:M50-1)),0)))

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Your formula does work for me.

Comment: Yes but change the 98.4 to a 99 and it doesn't move from the 98.1 to 99

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(, IF(N(
 {M44:M50;   ""}>{""; M44:M50})*IF(
 {M44:M50-1; ""}<{""; M44:M50}, 0, 1)=1, 
 {M44:M50;   ""}, "×")), "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank  you!  Since I am only having this in a single cell would you be able to construct a multiple criteria Index function instead?  This would greatly help me as I will likely need to add to or modify this some and have little understanding of Array formulas.  I want to say though that I greatly appreciate the application of Array formulas that you personally have done for me prior as they work excellent.

Comment: not sure what exactly are you asking but here I made you full explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/185zQHX0P2KC41DBuHHbv7K4onCdroTDKjT0DSKSM1IU/edit#gid=2002883572 check out all formulas there